# How to resolve the error: TypeError at /signup save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: django

I'm trying to register users using AbstractUser but I'm getting an error. Although I'm getting error, users still get registered but I can't handle login with the registered users.

The error goes thus:
[The error goes thus:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcoe4.png)

[The post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcP9w.png)

My views.py goes thus:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first-name']
        last_name = request.POST['last-name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone_no = request.POST['phone-no']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2'] 
        
        if password==password2:
            if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Username Taken')
                return redirect('signup')
            elif CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email Already Exist')
                return redirect('signup')
            else:
                CustomUser.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, username=username, email=email, phone_no=phone_no, password=password)
                CustomUser.save(commit=False)
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Passwords Not Matching')
            return redirect('signup')
    else:      
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

And my models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_end_user = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_smart_earner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_top_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Remove the `CustomUser.save(commit=False)`. It makes no sense, the record is created with the `create_user(...)` method, and you can only `.save()` model *objects*. Furthermore `.save()` does *not* accept a `commit=...` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `CustomUser.save(commit=False)`. It makes no sense, the record is created with the [**`.create_user(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user).

You can only call the [**`.save(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) on model *objects*, since these represent a record in the corresponding table. Using it on the `CustomUser` class makes not much sense, since it represents a table, and table itself is not altered when creating a record.

Furthermore your `.save()` call uses a parameter `commit=…`, but that does not make much sense either: the `.save(…)` of a `ModelForm` can accept a `commit=…` parameter, not the one for a `Model`.

I would however advise to work with a `ModelForm`. Such `ModelForm` can automatically validate unique fields, and save the created user. Django already has a basic `ModelForm` for this: the [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm). With some small changes, it can likely work for your custom user model.